# Create rule in outlook to filter messages sent to distribution list in the 'To' field only

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

My problem is as follows:
I get emails as part of a distribution list, which we'll call A. There are other distribution lists B & C who often have things sent TO them with A CC'd.

I'd like to set up a filter that can distinguish between messages sent TO A and those that are CC'd to A. And also do similar to B & C so they can all go to the correct folders. (In the event of being sent to more than one, A would take priority if in TO as that's my list)

So examples would work as follows:

- To: A; CC: B -> Folder A
- To: C; CC: A -> Folder C
- To: A, C; CC: B -> Folder A
- To: B,C; CC: A -> Folder B

Currently I've tried filtering using the 'sent to ' option with no luck as it doesn't distinguish between TO & CC. I tried specifically using mail headers, but I can't guarantee where in the headers the respective lists will be. (Can I potentially use wildcards?). I've also tried using 'except if sent to' but again that doesn't work as it can't distinguish between TO & CC.

I'd rather not move copies to the folders as it would use up too much storage space, and defeat the object as it would simply produce 3 identical folders containing what I would have in the inbox anyway.

So I guess my question is, can this be done?

Edit: I've also tried using the 'except if my name is in the CC column' option in the hope that it would recognise which mailing list I belong to (these lists are separable within Outlook). Sadly this doesn't work either.